# linked list insert function - passing a list by pointer

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

Im trying to create linked-list insert function that takes a list (or more correctly a pointer to it) then inserts the value to the end of the list.

```
void ll_insert(struct ll **l, int n){
  struct ll *temp=NULL;
  while ( (*l) != NULL){
    temp= (*l);
    (*l) = (*l)->next;
  }
  (*l)= (struct ll*)malloc(sizeof(struct ll));
  (*l)->n=n;
  (*l)->next=NULL;
  if (temp) temp->next= (*l);
}


int main(void){
  struct ll *l=NULL;                                                                                                                                                         
  ll_insert(&l, 1);
  printf("%d ", l->n);
  ll_insert(&l, 1);
  ll_insert(&l, 2);
  ll_insert(&l, 3);
  printf("%d ", l->n); 

}
```

The output after running the code above is 1 3. This is no surprise, since

```
(*l) = (*l)->next;
```

updates the list to point to to the end node, and every time I run insert(...) the list's head is updated to point to the end (if im not wrong). What's the way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the pointer to pointer correctly: this line in the `while` loop

```
(*l) = (*l)->next;
```

should be

```
l = &((*l)->next);
```

If you use it that way, you wouldn't need your `temp` variable at all.

Since this is C, not C++, it is OK to not cast `malloc`.

Comment: Could you please further explain the difference between the two cases?

Comment: @Smokie The first is an assignment of a pointer `next` itself to the pointer pointed to by `l`; the second one is an assignment of a pointer **to** `next` to the variable `l` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your function should only change *l if it is inserting into an empty list, as this is the only case where the first element of the list changes.  This can be accomplished by using a local variable instead of *l inside of your function for those cases (initialized to *l).

Answer (score 0):

if you don't move the pointer l, then it remains at the head of the list. First assign l to temp, then move temp along the list but leave pointer l alone.